# glClear before XMapWindow (prevent undefined graphical buffer)

Tags: c, glx

I'm struggling to handle the case where upon XMapWindow with glX, the buffer is undefined and as such the glx buffer will show undefined data before the first glXSwapBuffers is drawn.

I vaguely remember gl operations being meaningless before glXMakeCurrent, and glXMakeCurrent being meaningless before XMapWindow. Under these constraints, How does one control what will be drawn to an X11 GLX Window when it is mapped?

Seems like I would want to write the order as thus, but I still get undefined data (is this a vga driver specific issue that I should simply ignore?)

```
glXMakeCurrent(d, w, ctx);

glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glXSwapBuffers(d, w);

XMapWindow(d, w);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at a [Khronos reference example](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tutorial:_OpenGL_3.0_Context_Creation_(GLX)), this behavior happens in their example.

With a small patch, we can trigger exercise the undefined behavior every time.

```
--- OpenGL 3.0 Context Creation (GLX).orig.cc   2020-03-23 22:32:41.421765953 -0700
+++ OpenGL 3.0 Context Creation (GLX).edit.cc   2020-03-23 22:32:46.113753021 -0700
@@ -163,6 +163,8 @@

   printf( "Mapping window\n" );
   XMapWindow( display, win );
+  XSync( display, win );
+  sleep(2);

   // Get the default screen's GLX extension list
   const char *glxExts = glXQueryExtensionsString( display,
```

It looks like there is simply a defacto-race condition between XMapWindow and glx ini to glXSwapBuffers; best thing to do would be to ensure your first frame is swapped in ASAP and hope that you usually beat X to the punch.